# Western Parody - White hats vs Black hats

Tags: identify-this-movie, western, parody

This film is all about the good guys wear white hats and the bad guys wear black hats trope. I've tried looking it up but can't find it anywhere.

The hero (in a white hat) comes into town and clears it of all the bad guys (wearing black hats). As his reward is he is made sheriff and wins the heart of one of the townswoman.

The bad guys, wanting to get rid of the new sheriff, bring in their own white hat cowboy.
It is pointed out that the sheriff slept with the townswoman even though they were unmarried which is against the white hat code of honour.
He is replaced by the bad white hat as sheriff and goes into exile.

He is convinced to come back, where it is revealed the bad white hat has also unknowingly committed a large number of infractions himself.

- I would say this came out no later than the 80s.
- I've confused this for *Blazing Saddles* in the past, I think they had similar styles.
- There is a scene where a black hat knocks out a bull.

Comment: I googled cowboy knocking out bull and found a similar scene in Blazing Saddles. So I may be thinking of that scene.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Rustlers' Rhapsody"(1985)?

There are alot of white hats and black hats in this western parody, it's very similar in look and style to "Blazing Saddles,"and it has a good guy who it turns out isn't very good.

Here is the trailer from Youtube, I think you can also watch the entire movie there.

Comment: Yep - funny movie. "You're not a good guy at all!", "Of course not - I'm a lawyer, you idiot!"